# JavaFX - meaning of property "invalid"

Tags: javafx, listener, observable, bindable

In the context of JavaFX, in what sense is a property "invalid" when it is changed? I don't understand the reason for using this term.

A JavaFX property is an object that is observable and wraps a field value. So its listerners/observers are notified when the property updates or becomes **invalid.** What does it mean?

Comment: Here is a [blog on changes versus invalidations](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/02/08/when-to-use-a-changelistener-or-an-invalidationlistener/) by the past lead developer of the JavaFX 2 properties and binding implementation.

Answer (score 10):

I found good explanation here.

[image]

> When intProperty.set(7168) is called, it fires an invalidation event
>   to otherProperty. Upon receiving this invalidation event,
>   otherProperty simply makes a note of the fact that its value is no
>   longer valid. It does not immediately perform a recalculation of its
>   value by querying intProperty for its value. The recalculation is
>   performed later when otherProperty.get() is called. Imagine if instead
>   of calling intProperty.set() only once as in the above code we call
>   intProperty.set() multiple times; otherProperty still recalculates its
>   value only once.

As after testing I found this example.

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class InvalidMean{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        IntegerProperty num1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(15);
        IntegerProperty num2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
        // num2.bind(num1);
        // num1.set(56);
        System.out.println(num2);
    }
}
```

Run this code You will get this output:

```
IntegerProperty [value: 10]
```

Now remove the comment from commented lines. and you will get this output.

```
IntegerProperty [bound, invalid]
```

`num2`'s value become invalid because new value arrived but not updated yet. As [JavaFX Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) describe it just because of lazy evaluation.

> The JavaFX binding and property implementations all support lazy
>   evaluation, which means that when a change occurs, the value is not
>   immediately recomputed. Recomputation happens later, if and when the
>   value is subsequently requested.

If you want the value should be valid call `num2.getValue();` or `num2.get();` Before `System.out.println(num2);` you will see property will be valid then.

Note: In the above example `num2.bind(num1);` and `num1.set(56);` both will make invalid the value of `num2` because bind already changing the value of `num2` and `set()` also trying to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about lazy evaluation. This [video](http://www.devoxx.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5014845) of a conference in Devoxx 2011 helped me a lot to understand this concept.

Interesting stuff for you begins at ~5:00.

Comment: @UnKnown Can't find the video anymore, sorry.

Comment: @Spootted No problem. I also add an answer to this question read if you like and let me know If I'm wrong. Thanks.